# Python compare dict with csr_matrices as values

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, sparse-matrix, unit-testing

I have two variables `r` and `e` which both are dictionaries, with strings as keys and csr_matrices as values. Now I want to assert that they are equal. How do I do this?

**Try 1:**

```
from scipy.sparse.csr import csr_matrix
import numpy as np

def test_dict_equals(self):
    r = {'a': csr_matrix([[0, 0 ,1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0]])}
    e = {'a': csr_matrix([[0, 0 ,1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0]])}
    self.assertDictEqual(r, e)
```

This does not work:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all().
```

**Try 2:**

```
def test_dict_equals(self):
    r = {'a': csr_matrix([[0, 0 ,1.01], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0]])}
    e = {'a': csr_matrix([[0, 0 ,1.01], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0]])}
    self.assertListEqual(r.keys(), e.keys())
    for k in r.keys():
        np.testing.assert_allclose(r[k], e[k])
```

This does also not work:

```
AssertionError: First sequence is not a list: dict_keys(['a'])
```

**Try 3:**

```
def test_dict_equals(self):
    r = {'a': csr_matrix([[0, 0 ,1.01], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0]])}
    e = {'a': csr_matrix([[0, 0 ,1.01], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0]])}
    self.assertListEqual(list(r.keys()), list(e.keys()))
    for k in r.keys():
        np.testing.assert_allclose(r[k], e[k])
```

This does also not work:

```
TypeError: ufunc 'isinf' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

Answer (score 2):

The `assertDictEqual` function will invoke the `__eq__` method of objects. In the source code of `csr_matrix`, you can see there is no `__eq__` method.

You have to write a subclass of `csr_matrix` and then do the assertion. Here is an example for `numpy.ndarray` for you. Code must be similar.

```
import copy
import numpy
import unittest

class SaneEqualityArray(numpy.ndarray):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (isinstance(other, SaneEqualityArray) and
                self.shape == other.shape and
                numpy.ndarray.__eq__(self, other).all())

class TestAsserts(unittest.TestCase):

    def testAssert(self):
        tests = [
            [1, 2],
            {'foo': 2},
            [2, 'foo', {'d': 4}],
            SaneEqualityArray([1, 2]),
            {'foo': {'hey': SaneEqualityArray([2, 3])}},
            [{'foo': SaneEqualityArray([3, 4]), 'd': {'doo': 3}},
             SaneEqualityArray([5, 6]), 34]
        ]
        for t in tests:
            self.assertEqual(t, copy.deepcopy(t))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Hope it helps.:)

Answer (score 2):

Forget about the dictionary for the moment, and focus on comparing 2 `sparse` matrices.  They are not `numpy` arrays, so you can't directly use `np` methods.  That's why your 3rd try does not work.

There is a `scipy.sparse` unittesting directory.  I haven't examined it, but it might give you ideas beyond the ones I suggest below.

https://github.com/scipy/scipy/tree/master/scipy/sparse/tests

```
A=sparse.csr_matrix(np.arange(9).reshape(3,3))
B=sparse.csr_matrix(np.arange(9).reshape(3,3))
```

They are different objects

```
id(A)==id(B) # False
```

They have the same number of nonzeros

```
A.nnz == B.nnz  # True - just a comparison of 2 numbers
```

The data for this sparse format is contained in 3 arrays, `A.data`, `A.indices`, `A.indptr`.  So you could use `np` methods to test one or more of those

```
np.allclose(A.data, B.data)   # this would also compare dtype
```

You could also compare shape, etc.

Newer versions of `scipy` have implemented element by element comparators for sparse matrices.  `==` is implemented but likely to give you a warning:

> SparseEfficiencyWarning: Comparing sparse matrices using == is inefficient, try using != instead.

If the shapes match, this might be an efficient way of comparing to sparse matrices:

```
(A!=B).nnz==0
```

If the shapes don't match, `A!=C` returns `True`

And if they are small, you could compare their dense equivalents:

```
np.allclose(A.A, B.A)
```

Comment: Thanks. I am indeed testing A.data, A.indices and A.indptr now. The testing directory you refer to is test code for the implementation of csr_matrix, not helper functions for testing.

Comment: Note: it is possible to have two identical matrices, but with different indptr/indices/data arrays. The non-zero elements are then not in the same order for both. This results in false detection of non-equality.